# In R, why does the color parameter of geom_histogram() create a legend instead of changing the chart colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been following tutorials trying to change the colour of a histogram in R using `ggplot2`. However, it seems to be adding colour as a a new dimension, and is not changing the colour of the histogram bars as it seems like it should. Both `color` and `fill` seem to do the same thing.

I am using the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(`Column`)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., color = "#9999EE")) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm
                , args = list(mean = MeanVar
                              , sd = StdVar
                              )
                , col = "red"
                , size = 1
                ) +
  xlim(0,50)
```

`color` in the `stat_function` works fine and makes the line red. I've tried named-colours in the geom_histogram too but no difference.

[image: Example histogram where you see that color is being added into a legend as if it's a new dimension rather than changing the color of the histogram bars]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's probably a Q&A that explains this in details, or a chapter in https://ggplot2-book.org/, you're confusing mapped aesthetics and geom static attributes. Try `fill = "#9999EE"` as a an argument to the geom directly, not as an arg to aes().

Comment: It's in 2.4 : https://ggplot2-book.org/getting-started

Comment: Specifically, in section 2.4 look for the text *"If you want to set an aesthetic to a fixed value, without scaling it, do so in the individual layer outside of `aes()`."*

Comment: You aren't using the `color` parameter of `geom_histogram`. You are using the `color` parameter of `aes`.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed that the color was inside the aes() block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `color` parameter of the `aes` was being set instead of the `color` parameter of `geom_histplot()`. Though actually `color` was the line color, so I used `fill` instead.

Corrected code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(`Column`)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)
                     , fill = "#9999EE") + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm
                , args = list(mean = MeanVar
                              , sd = StdVar
                              )
                , col = "red"
                , size = 1
                ) +
  xlim(0,50)
```

Thanks to all commenters